# Can I use Firebase Admin SDK in AppEngine (Python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-admin

I need to deploy a project that must use Python in AppEngine, and I must use Firebase.

The point is that the use of secret is deprecated, and now Firebase uses "Firebase Admin SDK", that only has support on NodeJS or Java.

There is a possibility to use with the standard appEngine with Python?

Answer (score 2):

There is now a Firebase Admin SDK for Python as of one week ago. It only has support for creating custom tokens and verifying ID tokens as of now. However, it is tested on AppEngine. See documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup to see how to get started.